# Using find, grep and sed together

Tags: linux, sed, grep, find

I am trying to find all occurrences of files which have a specified string in them and then clear out the contents of all those files. So a file with "stringtofind" within it would subsequently be an empty file.

To do this I have tried the following, but I get errors:

With the following I get error: find: missing argument to `-exec'

```
 find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -i "stringtofind" -l -exec sed -i '/./d'
```

With the following I get error:

grep: /nis

/tset.any

/test2.file

/test.txt

: No such file or directory
sed: no input files

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -print | xargs -0 grep -i "stringtofind" -l | xargs sed -i '/./d'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your find command with the missing argument is very close to working.  try:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -i "stringtofind" -l {} \; -exec sed -i '/./d' {} \;
```

you just need to add a backslash escaped semi-colon to the end of each `-exec` action and add `{}` to let it know where to substitute the filename.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a file marker (`{}`) and termination (either `;` or `+`) to `-exec`. In addition I would suggest that you process the files with GNU parallel:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -li "stringtofind" {} + | 
  parallel sed "'/./d'" '{}'
```

To handle filenames with newlines in them you need to use zero termination as suggested by others:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -Zli "stringtofind" {} + | 
  parallel -0 sed "'/./d'" '{}'
```

#### Edit

Here's a non-parallel dependent alternative:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -Zli "stringtofind" {} + | 
  while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    sed '/./d' "$file"
  done
```

Comment: I can't use parallel, the systems I am going to use this with won't have it.

Comment: @user1166981: parallel is a self-contained perl script, so if perl is available it should work. You could also stick a while-loop at the end, see edit.

Comment: @user1166981: the while-loop alternative is only dependent on bash.

Comment: Just add `IFS=` to your read line to accommodate file names that start or end with spaces. It'd unlikely in this case, but you should always put `IFS=` before your reads by default unless you have a specific reason not to, makes you less likely to forget it when it is likely!

Comment: This is the only non-buggy solution posted, provided that Ed Morton's advice is followed, and far more efficient than `sed -i` to delete non-empty lines from a file.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with file names containing spaces. When using the `-0` argument to `xargs`, you should use `-print0` as final argument to `find`. `grep` should be happy with this.

However, while this will solve the issue in the pipe between `find` and `grep`, it will not allow to pass the zero-separated name in the pipe from `grep` to `sed`. Therefore, `sed` will still complain ...

Therefore, you should test with `grep` within `find` using `-exec`, and use a single pipe to `sed`, as follows. Note the use of double quotes `"` around the `{}` placeholder.

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -i "stringtofind" -q "{}" \; -print0 | xargs -0 sed '/./d'
```

It gives you the advantage to be able to get the list of the files that are going to be emptied by running only the first part of the command, up to but not including the `|`.

Comment: hello, I get this error:sed: can't read /tset.txt
/test2.file
: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried without the `sed` command? Simply listing the files that gonna be emptied.

Comment: find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -print -exec grep -i "stringtofind" -q {} \;

Comment: gave me: /nis
/tset.txt
/test2.file
/test.file

Comment: Looks OK. Try piping to `xargs -0 ls -l`. Does it list the files correctly?

Comment: You have to remove the `-print` in the middle of the `find` parameters.

Comment: Ok it is definately finding the right file, this time I put a test string in a test file in my root folder, set the depth to 2, and used your code. Here is the output:

Comment: sed: can't read /root/.bash_history

/root/test.txt

: No such file or directory

Comment: The text within the file remains and wasn't deleted.

Comment: find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -i "stringtofind" -q "{}" \; -print0 | xargs -0 sed '/./d'

Comment: gives this :sed: can't read /root/.bash_history /root/test.txt : No such file or directory

Comment: and /root/test.txt is the only file with "stringtofind" in it so it is finding it seems

Comment: Use the additional parameter for sed: `xargs -0 sed -i -e '/./d'`. They are important for actually removing the file content. But I can't find out why sed tells about "No such file or directory"!

Answer (score 1):

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f|xargs grep -l 'string'| xargs perl -pi -e 's/.*\n//g'
```

this above command will delete even the newlines in the file.If you want to retain the new lines and just delete the content in every line use below:

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f|xargs grep -l 'string'| xargs perl -pi -e 's/.//g'
```

Comment: I want to delete all the text in the file

Comment: `>file` will delete all the text in a file, no need for sed, perl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
$ for file in $(find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f  -exec grep -li stringtofind '{}' \;)
> do
>   > $file
> done
```

Comment: Would fail for files names containing spaces or globbing characters, Never write `for file in $(find..)`, write `find.. | while IFS= read -r file` instead to accommodate file names with spaces in them. And always quote your variables - write `"$file"` not `$file`.